# How to test if button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm working with React Testing Library. The problem I have is that `fireEvent` doesn't trigger, and the error throws, is following:

```
   Expected number of calls: >= 1
   Received number of calls:   0
```

For this particular test do I need to work with `@testing-library/react-hooks`? Do I need to render my Product component wrapped on context provider where the function is imported from?

`Product.tsx` component

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import { useProducts } from "./ContextWrapper";
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import { articleProps } from "./types";

const Product: FunctionComponent<{ article: articleProps }> = ({
  article,
}) => {
  const { handleAddToCart } = useProducts(); // this is from global context
  return (
      <Button
        aria-label="AddToCart"
        onClick={() => handleAddToCart(article)}
      >
        Add to cart
      </Button>

  );
};

export default Product;
```

`Product.test.tsx`

```
import React from "react";
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Product from "./Product";
import { act, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";

const article = {
  name: "samsung",
  variantName: "phone",
  categories: [],
};

const renderProduct = () => {
  return render(
    <ContextProvider>
      <Product article={article} />
    </ContextProvider>
  );
};

//first test just tests if button exists with provided content and works fine
test("renders product", () => {
  render(<Product article={article} />);
  const AddToCartbutton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /AddToCart/i });
  expect(AddToCartbutton).toHaveTextContent("Add to cart");
});
// this test throws the error described above
test("test addToCart button", () => {
  renderProduct();
  const onAddToCart = jest.fn();
  const AddToCartbutton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /AddToCart/i });
  fireEvent.click(AddToCartbutton);
  expect(onAddToCart).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

`ContextWrapper.tsx`

```
import React, {createContext, useContext, ReactNode, useState} from "react";
import { prodProps } from "../types";

type ProductContextProps = {
  productData: prodProps;
  handleAddToCart: (clickedItem: productPropsWithAmount) => void;

};

const ProductContextDefaultValues: ProductContextProps = {
  productData: null as any,
  handleAddToCart:null as any;
};

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

const ProductContext = createContext<ProductContextProps>(
  ProductContextDefaultValues
);

export function useProducts() {
  return useContext(ProductContext);
}

const ContextWrapper = ({ children }: Props) => {
  const { data } = useGraphQlData();
  const [productData, setProductData] = useState<Category>(data);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState<prodProps[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setProductData(data);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const handleAddToCart = (clickedItem: prodProps) => {
    setCartItems((prev: prodProps[]) => {
      return [...prev, { ...clickedItem }];
    });
  };

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider
      value={{
        productData,
        handleAddToCart,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ContextWrapper;
```

Comment: You need to wrap the components you're testing inside the Provider. You can have a setup for your tests separately if all components being tested need to be wrapped. Also, you should throw an error if the context is being used outside the Provider, if you would've done so then your first test would have also failed.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render

Comment: Can you add your ContextWrapper.tsx here?

Comment: Hi @LuisPauloPinto I updated my post adding context component

Comment: I tried to render  Product component wrapped in Context Provider, but does't work again.

Comment: There's currently no connection at all between your test double and the thing you're trying to test. How could there be: onAddToCart is defined _after_ the component gets rendered and the only other line it appears in is the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to create Button Component and test it separately like this:

```
const onClickButton = jest.fn();
await render(<Button onClick={onClickButton} />);
const AddToCartbutton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /AddToCart/i });
await fireEvent.click(AddToCartbutton);
expect(onClickButton).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to mock `ContextWrapper`, as your test is specifically referring to `Product` component.

So, you could do something like this into your test:

```js
import * as ContextWrapper from '--- PATH TO ContextWrapper ---';


test('test addToCart button', () => {
  /// mockFunction
  const onAddToCart = jest.fn();

  jest.spyOn(ContextWrapper, 'useProducts').mockImplementationOnce(() => ({
    productData: {
      example_prodProp1: 'initialValue1',
      example_prodProp2: 'initialValue2',
    },
    // Set mockFunction to handleAddToCart of useProducts
    handleAddToCart: onAddToCart,
  }));

  render(<Product article={article} />);

  const AddToCartbutton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /AddToCart/i });

  fireEvent.click(AddToCartbutton);

  expect(onAddToCart).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    prodProp1: 'samsung',
    prodProp2: 'phone',
  });
});
```

In this line `jest.spyOn(ContextWrapper, 'useProducts').mockImplementation` we are mocking `useProducts` return value and setting the `handleAddToCart` function to your mockFunction and that's how you can check if it has been called.

* This test is strictly focused on `Product` component and you just want to garantee that the component calls the `handleAddToCart` function from `ContextWrapper`.

For test how `handleAddToCart` should work, you can create a specific test for the `ContextWrapper`.